# Developping an angularJS app using a tomcat server

Tags: angularjs, maven, tomcat

Hi stackoverflow community,

I'm on a project that imposes developping a web app with these technologies:

- AngularJs app calling the back-end (the back-end API already existing)
- this app will be hosted on Tomcat, with maven as a build tool.

Now I installed eclipse, configured maven and tomcat on it, and i want to start with my first html page. The problem is that I can't find how to deploy an html page (as a start) with these technologies without using a servlet.

I want to generate a war file  using maven that would be deployed in tomcat server without defining servlets in web.xml.
All i can find on the internet is how to manually deploy angularJs apps on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [github project](https://github.com/GermanoGiudici/angularjs-maven-tomcat-seed) that might be very useful, I'll try to follow the same project structure.